# Why my post method in jquery mobile is not working?

Tags: php, jquery

This code is not working. The post method in jquery is not sending data... What is wrong? I'm trying to send the select element data to the index file by the help of jquery `post` method, but it is not working...

I tried the `get` also not working .....

let me know if anything is wrong....

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);

    function mul($x,$y){
            $z = $x * $y;
            return $z;
    }
    function plus($x,$y){
            $z = $x + $y;
            return $z;
    }
    function minus($x,$y){
            $z = $x - $y;
            return $z;
    }
    function divide($x,$y){
            $z = $x / $y;
            return $z;
    }
?>
<form>
    <select name="operator" id="se">
            <option value=1>Plus</option>
            <option value=2>Minus</option>
            <option value=3>Multiply</option>
            <option value=4>Divide</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="but" Value="Select Action">
</form>
<form action="index.php" method="post">

        <input type="number" name="one">
        <input type="number" name="two">
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $_POST["select"]; ?>">

</form>
<p>OUTPUT: <?php 
                if($_POST["select"] == 1){echo plus($_POST["one"],$_POST["two"]);}
                if($_POST["select"] == 2){echo minus($_POST["one"],$_POST["two"]);}
 ?></p>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

     $("#but").click(function(){
     var f=$("#se").val();
        $.post("index.php",{select:f});

     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Check the network requests in developer console... Is it sending something?  If not, you should wrap your function in $.ready()

Comment: Why are you using two forms? You are aware that your JavaScript only sends the value of the select, but not the values of the two text inputs?